# Icons and UI drawing problems after upgrading to 21.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, icons, themes

On one of my machines, I had been on 20.04 for a while and decided to upgrade to 21.04 just earlier. Everything went fine except for some weird problems with the UI and redraw issues. Icons appear correctly sometimes and just red squares the other times. Certain sections do not appear until I hover on them. Attaching couple of screenshots for reference:
[image] and [image]

As seen in these screenshots, you can see that:

- Instead of regular icon, you can see red square on "Show all monitors" and "Left" on "position on screen".
- The "restore" and "minimize" buttons on appbar do not show up or show up highlighted only on hover or after hovering on it
- You can see settings icon and toggle background but not the actual text on that section just below the screen position section.

I tried re-installing nvidia driver, switching to on-demand and power saving mode. Tried re-installing yaru-theme-* (except for yaru-theme-unity which I don't need). Anyone run into this issue and have found a solution?

Update: I have determined that this only happens if I have external monitors attached. I am yet to do more deep dive on what it could be.

Comment: Ubuntu has two upgrade paths; via every release (ie. 20.04 to 20.10, from 20.10 to 21.04) OR you can *jump* from 1 LTS to the next LTS (ie. 20.04 to 22.04.1).  Your upgrade path is outside of the QA-tested supported paths so if you want a more perfect upgrade - use a QA-tested path next time.  You didn't say which stack you were using (if it was HWE, there was no change as 20.04.3 using HWE is the 21.04 stack), however if you were using GA stack then that is a *huge* change. I've seen the issues you describe on certain hardware  fixed by switching kernel stacks (alas not an option on non-LTS)

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Next time, I will keep that in mind. I was on 20.04.3 prior to this upgrade. Also, I noticed this only occurs when I've external monitors plugged in

Comment: Sorry meant to say yes it was HWE